# Preference does not reflect the updated default value from xml file in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

below is my implementation

```
<resources>
    <bool name="mypreference_default">true</bool>
</resources>
```

when I change value from `true` to `false` or `false` to `true`, my application does not can not get the updated value. How can I retrieve updated value? below is my implementation:

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="@bool/mypreference_default"
    android:key="mypreference"
    android:title="@string/mypreference_title" />
```

And

```
SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Boolean value = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.mypreference_default);
Boolean b = p.getBoolean("mypreference", value);
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a value set for this preference? The default value only applies if no value is set. You could try uninstalling the app completely before reinstalling, or clearing all app data.

Comment: Where do you update the preference, please post that code. Maybe there's some error while updating.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You have to set the default first oncreate of your activity method:

```
@Override 
    protected void onCreate() 
    { 
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean autoStart = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("mypreference", true);

     {...} 
    }
```

Comment: You have to do no such thing, the question clearly shows that the default value is specified in the preference.xml file.